# React - Redux: how get state or props in a function dispatched from mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a presentational component:

```js
export const UsersPresentational = props => {

    const columns = [
        {
            name: 'Email',
            selector: 'email',
            sortable: true,
        }
    ]

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col><h1 className="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Utenti</h1></Col>
            </Row>
            <Card>
                <Card.Body>
                    <Datatable
                        columns={columns}
                        data={props.items}
                        {...props}
                    />
                </Card.Body>
            </Card>
            <ModalDetail
                showModalDetail={props.showModalDetail}
                componentDetail={
                    <User item={props.item} />
                }
                {...props}
            >
            </ModalDetail>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: state.users.items,
        showModalDetail: state.users.showModalDetail,
        idCompany: state.users.idCompany
    }
}
  
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        fetchItems: (orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage) => fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, dispatch),
    }
}

const fetchItemsByIdCompany = (orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, dispatch) => {

    dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage))
    // I need really a...
    // dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, props.idCompany))

}
  
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(UsersPresentational)
}

const fetchItemsByIdCompany = (orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, dispatch) => {

    dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage))
    // I need really a...
    // dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, props.idCompany))
    
}
  
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(UsersPresentational)
```

I need to pass a props (`props.idCompany` or `state.users.idCompany`) to `dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage))`.

It need to be really `dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, props.idCompany))`

Comment: If the id is in `state.users.idCompany` and your action is a thunk then why pass in the id when dispatching it. The second thunk parameter is the getState function and you can use that in your thunk to get `state.users.idCompany`

Answer (score 0):

You can use useDispatch Hook to dispatch an action and pass prop values as an argumnet. In this case you do not really need to map any dispatch action in the mapDispatchToProps (I have modified this method).

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

export const UsersPresentational = props => {
  const { idCompany } = props;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // Invoke this method dispatching the action
  // You can access the props within this method
  const fetchItemsByCompanyId = (orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage,) => {
    dispatch(usersActions.fetchItemsByIdCompany(orderBy, orderWay, page, perPage, idCompany))
  }

  // .... Rest of your code
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        items: state.users.items,
        showModalDetail: state.users.showModalDetail,
        idCompany: state.users.idCompany
    }
}
  
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        dispatch
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
)(UsersPresentational)
```